# How can I get the same results as apply_filters('the_content) without using that tag / filter?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a plugin that I'll describe as CMS lite. I create a custom post type. I store content in those entries. I then use a shortcode to insert content from the custom post posts into my main posts. This way I can insert the same short code in multiple reg. posts but only have to update once in the custom post(s).

In order to get the content of the custom post type to maintain it's WYSIWYG-ness (? hehe) I use apply_filters('the_content',...) on that content. Duh? Right?

The problem is, if there's a plugin (e.g., Sociable) that appends to the end of the content the apply_filters('the_content',) is adding that stuff to my custom post type content too. Needless to say, I don't need - nor want - multiple instances of social media share too icons splatted all up in my content area :)

I wanted the markup/formatting of apply_filters('the_content'...) but I can't run it through that without muckin' stuff up.

Help?

Comment: Why is it that everytime I post a question on StackOverflow I then find the answer within an hour after. For those who are curious, I think this should do the trick: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpautop

Answer (score 0):

Good question. I found two ways to do this:

1) Write your own function. This is especially useful if you're trying to parse a block of text in a script that loads outside of the WordPress environment. I found this to be useful in this situation:

```
function nl2p($str) {
    $arr=explode("\n",$str);

    for($i=0;$i<count($arr);$i++) {
        if(strlen(trim($arr[$i]))>0)
            $out.='<p>'.trim($arr[$i]).'</p>';
    }
    return $out;
}
```

2) (And I know you've already stumbled upon this yourself) you can use `<?php echo wpautop($post->post_content); ?>` to make your paragraphs.

Hope this helps!!